# Maximum value for the GCI index is not correct

Tags: qgis, vegetation-index, maximum

I'm working with QGIS 3.28.6 software. I have calculated the GCI index using a raster calculator. The formula used GCI = (NIR/GREEN)-1.
Unfortunately, the max values obtained are not in the range which means the value is too big. This resulting the GCI image becoming dark.

Is there any solution to this problem?

[image: GCI index information from the calculation]

Comment: How did you calculate GCI index? How is it related to DEM? Please mention the steps in details.

Comment: I used the NIR and the Green band from the multispectral images.  Then, I used a raster calculator to calculate the GCI index based on the formula GCI = (NIR/GREEN)-1.

Comment: why are you using such an old version of qgis?

Comment: Thas was a mistake, QGIS 3.28.6 actually.

Comment: Have you inspected the underlying raster data at a point where you are getting the max values? Unless there's other information you haven't provided, this sounds more like a data issue

Comment: I cannot find the max value = 4.071e+17 when I used the 'identify features' to extract the data, the highest value I can get is around 12 to 13 only. May I ask what kind of data issue for this error?  I'm really new to QGIS software so I don't know what I can do to fix this problem.

Comment: Please provide min/max values and data type of the NIR and Green bands. They should be floating point reflectance values with range 0.0-1.0.

Comment: For the Green band, min = 0.0408 and max = 0.6374. For the NIR band, min = 0.1628 and max = 1.0032. The data type is Float32 for both bands.